# Google Cloud Launcher: Single node file server deployment failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nfs, google-cloud-launcher

I'm trying to deploy a Single Node File Server as referred to in the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-tensorflow-jupyterhub-classrooms

When I follow the instructions, the instance appears to come up OK, but NFS does not appear to be running. When I try to mount from another instance with

`sudo mount -t nfs jupyterhub-filer-vm:/jupyterhub /mnt`

I get

`mount.nfs: Connection timed out`

When I inspect the filer instance from the Compute Engine UI (https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instancesDetail/zones/us-east1-d/instances/jupyterhub-filer-vm), I see

```
Custom metadata

ADMIN_PASSWORD  xxx
ATTACHED_DISKS  jupyterhub-filer-vm-jupyterhub
C2D_STATUS  DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
ENABLE_NFS  enable:True
ENABLE_SMB  enable:False
FILE_SYSTEM xfs
STORAGE_POOL_NAME   jupyterhub
```

The documentation suggests

`gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag=-L3000:localhost:3000 --project=workpop-dev --zone us-east1-d jupyterhub-filer-vm`

and then accessing `localhost:3000` in a browser to access a performance dashboard.  The ssh command connects me to the instance, but the browser returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` and in the ssh session I see
`channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`.

Within the ssh session, I try

`$ ps -e | grep nfs`

and it returns nothing.

`$ cat /etc/exports`

returns a default file containing only comments.

So I look for the disk with `$ sudo find / -name "jupyterhub*"` but this returns nothing. Poking around some more, I see `/opt/c2d/setup.log` which has the following lines at the the end:

```
VIRTUAL_IP =
+ readonly ZFS_KERNEL_CONFIG=/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf
+ ZFS_KERNEL_CONFIG=/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf
+ networks=(10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.1)
+ readonly networks
+ readonly DISK_PREFIX=/dev/disk/by-id/google
+ DISK_PREFIX=/dev/disk/by-id/google
+ readonly DATA_DEVICE=/dev/disk/by-id/google-jupyterhub-filer-vm-data
+ DATA_DEVICE=/dev/disk/by-id/google-jupyterhub-filer-vm-data
+ [[ xfs = \z\f\s ]]
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ case "${FILE_SYSTEM}" in
+ mkfs.xfs -L jupyterhub /dev/disk/by-id/google-jupyterhub-filer-vm-data
/dev/disk/by-id/google-jupyterhub-filer-vm-data: No such file or directory
Usage: mkfs.xfs
/* blocksize */         [-b log=n|size=num]
/* metadata */          [-m crc=0|1,finobt=0|1]
/* data subvol */       [-d agcount=n,agsize=n,file,name=xxx,size=num,
                            (sunit=value,swidth=value|su=num,sw=num|noalign),
                            sectlog=n|sectsize=num
/* force overwrite */   [-f]
/* inode size */        [-i log=n|perblock=n|size=num,maxpct=n,attr=0|1|2,
                            projid32bit=0|1]
/* no discard */        [-K]
/* log subvol */        [-l agnum=n,internal,size=num,logdev=xxx,version=n
                            sunit=value|su=num,sectlog=n|sectsize=num,
                            lazy-count=0|1]
/* label */             [-L label (maximum 12 characters)]
/* naming */            [-n log=n|size=num,version=2|ci,ftype=0|1]
/* no-op info only */   [-N]
/* prototype file */    [-p fname]
/* quiet */             [-q]
/* realtime subvol */   [-r extsize=num,size=num,rtdev=xxx]
/* sectorsize */        [-s log=n|size=num]
/* version */           [-V]
                        devicename
<devicename> is required unless -d name=xxx is given.
<num> is xxx (bytes), xxxs (sectors), xxxb (fs blocks), xxxk (xxx KiB),
      xxxm (xxx MiB), xxxg (xxx GiB), xxxt (xxx TiB) or xxxp (xxx PiB).
<value> is xxx (512 byte blocks).
```

At this point, I'm convinced that something has gone wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, this is also tracked at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-jupyter-classroom/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the disk name.

Try it with the default value: Storage Name = data

( It finished the setup for me without an error and localhost:3000 is loading correctly. I'm not sure if it creates errors later in the lab.)

Comment: FYI The lab documentation got updated to "Storage Name = data". Custom storage name support will may come in future updates.